# Increase the string by spaces to a specified width

Tags: javascript

I can add only one space after `arr[i]`, but i need spaces to depend on the `.length` of the string

```js
var addSpace = function(str, maxLength) {
  if (maxLength < str.length) {
    return str;
  } else if (maxLength > str.length) {
    var arr = str.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = arr[i] + " ";
    }
    return arr.join(" ");
  }
}
console.log(addSpace("This is my string", 30));
```

Comment: can you please paste your code, its easier to inspect then seeing it in image

Comment: What is expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a counter and add spaces to all splitted items, except the last one until the length is equal to the wanted length.

```js
var addSpace = function(string, length) {
        var array = string.split(" "),
            i = 0;

        if (length <= string.length) {
            return str;
        }
        length -= string.length;
        while (length--) {
            array[i++ % (array.length - 1)] += ' ';
        }
        return array.join(" ");
    },
    result = addSpace("This is my string", 30);

console.log(result);
console.log(result.length);
```

Comment: Thanks!;)Thanks!;)Thanks!;)

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
function addSpace(s,maxLength){
  return s.length >= maxLength ? s : s + " ".repeat(maxLength-s.length);
}

console.log(addSpace("This is my string", 30),"!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const resetStringLength = (text, count, char = ' ', before = 0, offset = 0) => {
    if (count < 1) throw new Error('count < 1');
    if (before < 0) throw new Error('before < 0');
    if (offset < 0) throw new Error('offset < 0');

    text = `${(' ').repeat(offset)}${text}${(' ').repeat(offset)}`;
    char = char[0];

    const after = count - text.length - before;
    if (after < 1) throw new Error('after < 1');

    return (
        char.repeat(before) +
        text +
        char.repeat(after)
    );
};
```

```js
const resetStringLength = (text, count, char = ' ', before = 0, offset = 0) => {
    if (count < 1) throw new Error('count < 1');
    if (before < 0) throw new Error('before < 0');
    if (offset < 0) throw new Error('offset < 0');

    text = `${(' ').repeat(offset)}${text}${(' ').repeat(offset)}`;
    char = char[0];

    const after = count - text.length - before;
    if (after < 1) throw new Error('after < 1');

    return (
        char.repeat(before) +
        text +
        char.repeat(after)
    );
};




const text = document.getElementById('text');
const count = document.getElementById('count');
const char = document.getElementById('char');
const before = document.getElementById('before');
const offset = document.getElementById('offset');

const result = document.getElementById('result');


const start = () => {
  try {
    result.innerText = resetStringLength(
      text.value, 
      count.value, 
      char.value, 
      before.value, 
      offset.value
    );
  } catch (e) {
    result.innerText = `Error ${e.message}`;
  }
};


text.oninput = () => start();
count.oninput = () => start();
char.oninput = () => start();
before.oninput = () => start();
offset.oninput = () => start();

start();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
section label {
  position: relative;
}
section label:not(:first-child) {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
section label input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  font-family: monospace;
}

pre {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <label>Text: <input id="text" value="Hallo World!" autocomplete="off"></label>
  <label>Count: <input id="count" value="20" autocomplete="off"></label>
  <label>Char: <input id="char" value="-" autocomplete="off"></label>
  <label>Before: <input id="before" value="2" autocomplete="off"></label>
  <label>Offset: <input id="offset" value="1" autocomplete="off"></label>
</section>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```